# PyTorch: load weights from another model without saving

Tags: python, pytorch

Assume that I have two models in PyTorch, how can I load the weights of model 1 by weights of model 2 without saving the weights?

Like this:

```
model1.weights = model2.weights
```

In TensorFlow I can do this:

```
variables1 = model1.trainable_variables
variables2 = model2.trainable_variables
for v1, v2 in zip(variables1, variables2):
    v1.assign(v2.numpy())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two instances of the same model (must subclass `nn.Module`), then you can use [`nn.Module.state_dict()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) and [`nn.Module.load_state_dict()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict). You can find a brief introduction to state dictionaries [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/what_is_state_dict.html).

```py
model1.load_state_dict(model2.state_dict())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways to do that.

```
# Use load state dict
model_source = Model()
model_dest = Model()
model_dest.load_state_dict(model_source.state_dict())

# Use deep copy
model_source = Model()
model_dest = copy.deepcopy(model_source )
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another way to the solution, although it is the same as `load_state_dict()`, but might be useful when `load_state_dict()` throws error for any reason:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    for source_param, target_param in zip(model_to_copy_from.parameters(), model.parameters()):
        target_param.data.copy_(source_param.data)
```